# Which Android API issues Scan Request and Responses

Tags: android, android-ble

Is it Android gatt connect or Android scan(getBluetoothLeScanner) which results in the Scan Request and Response?
If we know the BLE Device address , can we directly connect it to without discovering the service?

Answer (score 1):

In Android BLE scan, the result for scan request will return in the way you want, for example

```
List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();

ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
        .setServiceUuid(uuid)
        .setDeviceAddress(address)
        .setDeviceName(name)
        .build();
filters.add(filter);
```

And scan response will return at

> onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result)

```
ScanCallBack mCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
            if (result != null){
                BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
                mDeviceList.add(device);
                removeDuplicateWithOrder(mDeviceList);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            super.onBatchScanResults(results);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
            Log.e("TAG", "Scan failed " + errorCode);
        }
    };
```

> If we know the BLE Device address , can we directly connect it to without discovering the service?

The answer is **YES** and you can follow this example

```
public boolean connect(final String address) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
        return false;
    }

    // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
    if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
            && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
        if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }
    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
    // parameter to false.
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
    mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
    return true;
}
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: The answer to the second question is a bit more advanced. You can only reliably connect to a device address if you have either scanned it since the last Bluetooth reset or it is bonded, due to lack of address type parameter in the API.

Comment: @Emil, in that case, I can use another callback to scan and connect redirect to device without discovering the service. `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback()`. 
This callback will allow me to scan and add any device it found.

Comment: @DuyKyou if I am not wrong LeScanCallback is used till Android J and for future it is getBluetoothScanner().startScan()

Comment: @Emil yes it has already been connected and now trying to connect again but at different service but before that after disconnection I have called refresh cache.

Comment: @Raulp yes, I'm using `mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(...);`, because from the android API 21, LeScanCallback  is deprecated.

Comment: @Raulp for more detail about BLE advertise and scan , you can visit my project at https://github.com/hoaiduyit/advertisediscoverBLE